# Is there a sequel to part 3 of ‘Segments’ by Richard Malka?

Tags: segments

The name is "[Segments](http://www.glenatbd.com/bd/segments-tome-1-9782723473729.htm)" and it is written by [Richard Malka](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Malka). For now there is only part 1, 2 and 3, and then it just stops. I have no news about whether that story is planned to be continued.

Even if the link is in French, I've posted it anyway because this story is worth it. Especially if anyone can find an English copy.

[image][image][image]

**Does anyone know about a sequel, or does it already exist?**

Answer (score 3):

According to the publisher's website, [the last volume was published on December 2nd 2014](http://www.glenatbd.com/bd/segments-tome-3-9782723497107.htm), so if the story was left incomplete, then there will probably be a sequel.  Just give it some time for the announcement.

Comment: @Rocket If you were already yearning for the next book in this series less than a month after the last one came out, I strongly suggest you don’t start [*A Song of Ice and Fire*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Song_of_Ice_and_Fire).

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Hi I dont understand what you mean ?

Comment: @Rocket The author for [A Song of Ice and Fire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Song_of_Ice_and_Fire) takes his time writing in the series. The last novel took 6 years, while the latest is going on 4 years now. If you want to read the latest installment right away, like Segments, then don't start this series.

Comment: @DashControl ok perfect thx.. I'm not the patient type